# How to redirect to a specific page in webview when back button pressed?

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a working code which redirects to previous page in history in webview.

I want to redirect it to a specific page(example.com).

Can anyone tell how to do that?

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebview.canGoBack()) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                String currenturl = sharedPreferences.getString("currentpage", null);

                if (currenturl.contains("http://google.com/")){
                    mWebview.requestFocus();
                    mWebview.goBack();
//    mWebview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the current result?

Comment: takes you to previous page

Answer (score 0):

Found it after some trial and error

just remove

```
if (mWebview.canGoBack()){
```

Replace

```
mWebview.goBack();
```

With

```
mWebview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```